# Not finding PowerShell packages in Nexus OSS when the RequriedModules Attribute has a value in the Module Manifest

Tags: powershell, module, nuget, nexus, package-managers

I have been working on setting up a DevOps stack (source control, ci, package management) for our powershell modules.  I was playing with nexus OSS as a PM solution.  I am able to use the `Publish-Module` cmdlet to add modules to the nuget feed, as well as use `Install-Module` to install them from the same feed.  I started playing around with dependencies, the `RequiredModules` key in the Module Manifest.  And if I put a module in there, then publish it to the nexus (the dependent package needs to published first) it will complete, and I can go to the web interface and see the pkg in the feed, and see the other pkg as a dependency.  But when I then use `Install-Module` I keep getting an error

> PackageManagement\Install-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and module name 'MyModule'.
>   Try Get-PSRepository to see all available registered module repositories.
>   At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.1.1.0\PSModule.psm1:1826 char:21
>   + ...          $null = PackageManagement\Install-Package @PSBoundParameters
>   +                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power....InstallPackage:InstallPackage) [Install-Package], Ex
>      ception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage

now, if I remove the required module value from the manifest, it works again.  I went ahead and put up ProGet, and I do not have this issue, I can install the main package and the dependent one comes along too.  Thanks for any help or ideas!

Comment: Side note, I can still use `Install-Module` and install the required module.

Comment: Just set up Klondyke, works as expected as ProGet does.  Maybe ill just sue klondyke, seems very light weight.

Comment: So, here is a little more info on this.  If I use the `Publish-Module` and point it to the path rather then the name, it works.  Or, if I in the Manifest I use a hashtable of all the info needed `RequiredModules = @(@{ ModuleName = "NeededModule"; ModuleVersion = "1.0"; })`  So now I really don't know where the issue lies, but as I said, I don't have this issue with ProGet or Klondyke.